# api is returning empty Array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

[hi when I run this api/animals it is returning an empty array however it should return data in json format it is .Net 6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuiSb.png)

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AnimalsController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult GetAnimals(); 
        {
            var animals = new List<AnimalModel> 
            {
                new AnimalModel() { Name = "dog", Description = "4 legs"};
                new AnimalModel() { Name = "cat", Description = "4 legs" };
            };
            return Ok(animals);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code as code, not as images.

Comment: Add your code instead of images please.

Comment: You should probably read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: You seem to have a thing for semi-colons, try removing some.

Comment: try my code......

Answer (score 1):

- remove the semicolon in line 13
- remove the semicolon in line 15, and
  16 add (comma)**,**

then try to execute it

Answer (score 1):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AnimalsController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult GetAnimals()
    {
        var animals = new List<AnimalModel> 
        {
            new AnimalModel() { Name = "dog", Description = "4 legs"},
            new AnimalModel() { Name = "cat", Description = "4 legs" }
        };
        return Ok(animals);
    }
}

public class AnimalModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

[image]